# JSF not finding function

Tags: jsf, el

I'm having trouble with my JSF prog, it is throwing error msg like this

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: /addCus.xhtml: The class 'gDANIEL.CustomerController' does not have the property 'addCustomer'.


root cause 
javax.el.ELException: /addCus.xhtml: The class 'gDANIEL.CustomerController' does not have the property 'addCustomer'.
```

It is saying that addCustomer method does not exist in the class CustomerController, I really don't understand i've checked and in fact it does exist

CustomerController

```
    public String addCustomer() throws Exception{
    CustomerManager cusMgr = new CustomerManager();
    cusMgr.addCustomer(customerID, customerFirstName, customerLastName,customerAddress, customerPhone, customerEmail, notes);

    message = "Record Successfully Saved";
    return "add";
}
```

jsf page from where I'm calling the function

```
    <p:commandButton value ="Save Customer Information " action ="#{customerController.addCustomer}" update="outputmessage">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add brackets?

Comment: @Turo Brackets are not relevant ... see the duplicate